# Why does relatability to songs and their lyrics trigger so much emotion?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

I could be alone on this. Whenever I listen to some songs of any genre whose lyrics tell a story so relatable to my own experiences, I would always picture the memories and reminisce the good old days. I would become emotional inside and could not control myself to not think about the past. I always try to suppress these emotions, of course, but deep down I know I have been emotionally affected.

Is this normal? Why does this happen? Is this the true intention of the artist to use lyrics to play with our emotions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, obviously this is normal and music influence the emotions or the inner feeling of a person!!Considering the definition of lyrics as, “words placed to a melody” it would be impossible to talk about lyrics without talking about music. They support each other and work together to create one experience. Many studies have found the influence music has on emotions. These studies are fairly well balanced, showing that music is a tool that can positively or negatively affect mood. Lyrics are
a tool just as music is, and when partnered with positive psychology, can make a positive impact on the hundreds and thousands of people who listen to music on a daily basis.Most of the artists try put their own feelings in the songs they compose. Taftish intend to create some or the other feeling for their listeners. It may be positive or negative but the point it should kindle our emotions.

Answer (score 0):

Music is an emotional art. It generally IS the intention of the artist to give you an emotional experience of one kind or another.

The more relatable you find the lyrics, the easier it is for you to access that experience. Of course, songs can be relatable but not good, or good but not relatable, but the combination of both is undeniably powerful.

That's the reason so many songs are about universal experiences like love and heartbreak.